# What is the difference between Stochastic Hill Climbing and Simulated Annealing?

Tags: optimization

I am trying to use a simulated annealing algorithm to tune the weights of a neural network. I was going to use pybrain's `optimization.StochasticHillClimber` class to implement simulated annealing, but I realize that Stochastic Hill Climbing and Simulated Annealing may be different algorithms.

From the code of the `StochasticHillClimber` class, it looks like it does not decrease the Temperature `T` variable each iteration. Is this the only difference between stochastic hill climbing and simulated annealing?

Comment: OMSCS CS7641? :) I thought the same thing, it seems like the difference is in the temperature dropping. Scipy has an implementation of simulated annealing, but it was removed in 0.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between simulated annealing and stochastic hill climbing is just that the Temperature `T` each iteration in simulated annealing decreases, whereas in pybrain's current (version 0.3) `optimization.StochasticHillClimber` implementation, the Temperature stays constant.

In simulated annealing, as the temperature value drops, the algorithm is less likely to choose a new value if it is further from maximizing or minimizing the fitness function than the current value.